# how do i get rid of CSS animation delay at the end

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

My loading screen animates an svg path with css keyframe animation. I originally made the loading screen disappear once the page had loaded. However, on some computers the loader would disappear before it had finished it's animation which would leave you wondering what it was. To tidy this up I decided I wanted to make the loading screen disappear after the animation had completed.

I'm using jQuery to detect when the animation has completed. Currently it console logs a message to show it has finished. However, the message comes quite a while after the animation has finished.

Can anyone help me find out why the delay is so long and how I can get it to work sooner.

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obozVW)

Html

```
<svg version="1.1" id="wrapper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve"><path id="path" class="path" fill="none" stroke="#4b4949" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"  d="M100,259c3.8-4.9,16.5-5.1,33.1-3.3c3,0.3,6.1,0.1,8.9-0.9c2.9-1,5.3-2.5,6.3-4.7c0.6-1.1-0.6-2.4-1.7-2
c-2.3,0.8-3.7,3.6-3.5,6.7c0.3,4,3.9,6.8,7.9,6.5c6-0.5,14.1-3,25.6-7.6c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c-3.3,2.9-3.1,4.8,0.3,6.1
c1.1,0.4,2.3,0.6,3.5,0.6c9.4,0.1,11.4-8.1,8.1-9.7c-0.6-0.3-1.3,0.1-1.5,0.8c-0.8,3.6,1.3,4.9,7.9,4.4c9.5-1.8,18.5-6.2,24-5
c-5,2.7-6.3,6.8-3.1,10.1c1.3,1.4,3.4,1.8,5.1,1.1c3.2-1.3,4.6-4.2,4.2-8.8c2.2,16.8,27.8-4.7,39.7-2.3h4.2c-5.1-0.1-8.3,3.9-7,7.3
c0.5,1.4,2.1,2.2,3.6,2c6.1-0.7,6.7-8.7,5.4-15.8c-0.1-0.7-1.1-0.9-1.4-0.3c-6.3,9.6,17.4,30.1,30.6,7.7c3.4,8.7,12.2,8.7,26.3,0
v4.9c0,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.1c3.8-7.3,7.9-9.3,9-6.9c0.2,6.8,3.2,9,9.1,7c1.4-0.5,2.7-0.9,4.1-1.3l20.4-4.6c0,0,0,0,0,0.1
c-3.6,2.5-4.7,4.2-2.7,6.3c1.1,1.2,2.9,1.5,4.4,0.9c4.4-1.7,5.4-4.8,4-8.9c2.2,10.8,1.9,18-2.7,18.9c-1,0.2-2,0-2.7-0.7
c-2-2,0.7-5.2,5.1-7.6c4.4-2.3,9.4-3.2,14.4-2.6c7.9,0.8,19.2,2.5,26-6.3"/>
<path fill="none" class="path2" stroke="#4b4949" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M301.1,244.6c-0.3,0.5-0.4,1.1-0.3,1.7"/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 12s forwards;
} 

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash2 12s 0s forwards;
} 

@keyframes dash2 {
  40% {
    stroke-dashoffset:1001;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

JQuery

```
function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var t,
      el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var animations = {
    "animation"      : "animationend",
    "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
    "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
    "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
  }

  for (t in animations){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}
var $animationname = $('.path');

var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent();

$( document ).ready(function() {

        $animationname.one(animationEvent,
               function(event) {

     console.log("animation has ended");
   });

    });
```

Comment: seems to me that  stroke-dashoffset: 500; in animation would set the end of animation

Comment: this is what i mean http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMPorL

Comment: Thats worked great send it as an answer and i will select is as the answer. thanks so much i've been puzzling and playing around for hours @GCyrillus